# jQuery why is my function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why is my simple alert function is not firing? I am new to jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  function myfunc() {
    alert("jjj");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return myfunc()">
  <input type="text" onclick="myfunc()" name="values" />

  <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does it have to be jQuery?

Comment: This question is worth all of our time, but no one thinks it's worth voting up?

Comment: @j08691 not only was that edit not helpful and unnecessary, because the does not work, but you altered the question. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78852/288670) explains why that should not be done.

Comment: @ChristianJuth You need to rethink your comment. My edit exactly illustrates the problem with the function not defined message. All I did was take the code posted and make it runnable.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the issue has to do specifically with JavaScript and not the jQuery parts of your example.

Your `onclick` is accessing the function on the global scope, but your function definition is inside another function's scope and so it's in a 'closure' - and not accessible outside of the outer function's call object. Generally, you probably don't want to use `onclick` for these types of reasons - unless it's in some framework like angular where it's referencing to some function on a controller...

Here is an example of an event handler that will better suit you. (you should always make a test case like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/sjpq1x5j/) (since you are new to this, keep in mind that if you make a jsFiddle - you'll need to add jQuery in the js settings of the fiddle.)

### HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" onclick="myfunc()" name="values" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Done" class='js-formSubmit' />
</form>

<button class="js-button">test me</button>
```

### JS

```
$(function() {
  function myfunc() {
    alert("You can't get me from the global scope because I live in this scope.");
  }
});

$(function() {

  $('.js-formSubmit').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you don't want to send the form normally
    alert('hi!');
  });

  $('.js-button').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('hi!');
  });

});
```

Comment: The key word in the question was 'Why.'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function myfunc() {
            alert("jjj");

        }

    });
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function myfunc() {
        alert("jjj");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No real need for the `$`-part :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `myfunc` is nested in an outer function which again is nested in the `jQuery` ready function. So it is not visible outside the outer functions. Try the following way:

```js
    function myfunc() {
        function a () {
            alert("jjj");

        }
        return a;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return myfunc()">
    <input type="text" onclick="myfunc()()" name="values" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `ES6` you can do it with [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions like this:

```
()=> {
  alert("jjj");
}()
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The concept is neither jQuery or ES6 specific. Are you saying to this person - go learn about build tools and babel and npm and bower and THEN, use this other syntax?

Comment: @sheriffderek but if you really are gonna use build tools lets be real, learn CoffeeScript. Also yeah this isn't an answer.

Comment: CoffeeScript isn't going to make it through / I don't think. Everyone I know has a hard time with the syntax. Terrible for new team members.

Comment: I haven't had to use build tools to use ES6 unless I am going to deploy to production. ES6 is the future of Javascript and it doesn't hurt learning anything new.

Comment: I'd suggest learning how to interpret questions before I learned ECMAscript.

Answer (score -1):

I removed this wrapper you added because it was not necessary and it changes the scope of the defined function. `onclick` looks for `myfunc` in the window object, and since this wrapper function changes the scope `myfunc` is undefined.

What I deleted:

```
$(function() {
});
```

## Working example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return myfunc()">
  <input type="text" onclick="myfunc()" name="values" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
<script>
  function myfunc() {
    alert("jjj");
  }
</script>
```

## Working example using jQuery onload

If you want to add a wrapper function here is how you would do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#done").click(function(){
    alert("jjj"); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="values"/> 
  <input id="done" type="submit" value="Done"/>
</form>
```

`onsubmit="return myfunc()"` was also causing issues, so I removed it. This is very "real world case" scenario of a wrapper function. According to w3schools...

> The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been
>   loaded.
>
> Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good
>   place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the
>   example above.
>
> The ready() method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.